# Schedule Backup / Restore to Different SQL Server Instance

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two SQL Server installations on two different machines. On the first machine I have database 'CUSTOMERS' which I would like to, on a scheduled basis, backup and restore as 'BACKUP_CUSTOMERS' on the second machine.

I've created a shared folder on machine 2 which is able to be read/written to by both machines SQL server services.

I have created a SQL Server Agent Job to do this but I am a bit lost on the steps after backing it up.

First step is:

```
BACKUP DATABASE 
CUSTOMERS
TO DISK = '\\MACHINE_2\DB Backups\CUSTOMERS.bak'
WITH COMPRESSION;
```

Is it possible to restore it as the next step?

I know I could potentially create a job on machine 2 to restore at regular intervals but that is subject to timing since it would presumably fail if the backup is still running.

Comment: If the two servers are linked, you should be able to EXEC the RESTORE over the linked connection. This article may be of help: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/23800.fully-automated-sql-server-restore-script.aspx

Comment: The usual approach for "second machine backup" includes [SQL Server Replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/sql-server-replication). There are many flavors to keep a secondary database up-to-date. SQL Server version and edition restrictions may apply. Also, consider posting your question on [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/), which is part of the StackExchange network.

Comment: ...and is it a problem if the job on the Machine 2 fails? You can set it to retry several times...

Answer (score 0):

You can restore and rename database using below code

```
RESTORE DATABASE [DB_NAME] FROM DISK='\\MACHINE_2\DB Backups\CUSTOMERS.bak'
WITH 
   MOVE 'DB_NAME' TO 'C:\DB_NAME.mdf', -- DATABASE FILES PATH YOU CAN CHANGE IT TO YOU 
CUSTOME PATH ON YOUR MACHINE
   MOVE 'DB_NAME_log' TO 'C:\DB_NAME.ldf'-- DATABASE FILES PATH YOU CAN CHANGE IT TO YOU
```